# opentok archive callback POST data issue

Tags: php, post, archive, opentok, tokbox

I have a tokbox archive callback registered in my account which gets called every time there is a change in an archive - status:created, available etc.

I am working with PHP. According to the docs, the callback is triggered with a POST request to my callback file, that works fine.

I am able to check `if(isset($_POST)) {do something}`, however the $_POST var is an empty array. According to the docs, I believe there should be a JSON with info about the archive, but do not receive one. That is the issue.  I have checked the $_REQUEST variable also - no $_POST, $_GET, $_PUT either.

I am archiving on the TokBox servers not AWS or Azure, and am using the trial account.

Is the callback called with actual POST data in the body?

Any tips for finding out if data is sent?

Thanks.

Comment: Manik here from the OpenTok team. Could you please make sure that the archive callback is set in the Archiving section on the dashboard and not the session monitoring section? Please also ensure that you start and stop an archive to see the changes.

Comment: Yes, those are both confirmed. I receive the call back when the archive is started, stopped, and available for each recording session.  The call back is called on each of these events, but no PUT info is getting through.

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$fileObj = json_decode($body, true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.